# Inbox by Gmail -- how to print entire conversation?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I'm using Inbox by Gmail and want to print an entire conversation of about 50 emails. I can't find the button for printing the entire conversation (group of emails). Any hint?

Comment: Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to print an entire conversation from Inbox. All you can do is print individual messages.

You'll need to switch to regular Gmail to print the whole conversation.

I suppose this is not surprising, since Inbox is still in Preview. You should use the "Feedback" option to let Google know that this is an important feature. Perhaps they'll prioritize it for the next set of enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

The [Gmail Print All Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-print-all-pro/jobhgbnpobdpmpdhcnailgemedfhjbho) and [Pretty Print Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pretty-print-gmail/gdanfldekhdgkbmdoeapbgbcpfglkflg) apps in the Chrome Play Store helped with this exact problem. With this, I could print the whole conversation (label).

Comment: Could you at least link to the extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can print all conversations of a particular email by clicking the print symbol. 
Each conversation again has print option separately and it will be user's choice to decide whether whole conversation or a particular conversation to be printed.

Control + P is easiest way to achieve this.

After you select print option, Chrome browser provides you a very good option to Save as PDF also.

Answer (score -1):

ctrl + p

Or

print screen then paste it on paint

I hope this would help

Comment: I think that would need a huge screen, for 50 email messages...

Comment: or paste it on your word? maybe?

Comment: There is no Paint on OSX or Linux in case you're using it instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry guys I guess I didn't help at all :(

Comment: @EricBuenaventura - You should take this chance to improve your answer so you can earn reputation points on your improved high quality helpful answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can forward the last mail to yourself and print that mail.
Then you have all the mails in chronological order.

Comment: Only if all of the messages quoted all of the messages before it.